# Jquery autocomplete with php source

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

I would like to use the jquery autocomplete "function" with a php file as the source. I don't get why it is not working. If I use data entered in a variable everything works fine. Hope someone can help. Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc.

My HTML:

```
<input id="moi" type="text"/>
```

My JS :

```
$(function() {
        $( "#moi" ).autocomplete({
            source: "php/search_loc.php",
            minLength: 2
        });
    });
```

My PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
require("../inc/connect.inc.php");
mysql_set_charset('utf8'); 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM search_loc");
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo $row['srl_loc'].'<br>';}

?>
```

Comment: I've never used the jQuery autocomplete plugin, but I'm fairly certain that it's not delimited by `<br>`.

Comment: And you have twice `$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);` in there. is this on purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your PHP script should return JSON data,

In the Jquery UI [autocomplete doc](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote)

```
The datasource is a server-side script which returns JSON data,
```

Comment: You could put "[" before <?php, "]" after ?> and separate your strings with a ",". Or use json_encode on an array where you put your values

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a `json_encode()` function:

```
echo json_encode($row['srl_loc']).'<br />';
```