# autocomplete plugin not passing values in php jquery

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

I am using a autocomplete

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/

And below i have two pages `index.php` and `ajx_page.php`

### index.php

```
<form name="send_coup_ajx_form" id="send_coup_ajx_form" method="post">

    <select name="member_type" id="member_type">
        <option value="customer_type">Customer</option>
        <option value="BPartner_type">Business Partner</option>                
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="sel_rad" id="resultant_text" />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="go" />

</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){


        $("#resultant_text").autocomplete("ajx_page.php", {
            width: 260,
            matchContains: true,
            //mustMatch: true,
            //minChars: 0,
            //multiple: true,
            //highlight: false,
            //multipleSeparator: ",",
            selectFirst: false
        });

    });

</script>
```

And  below code for

### ajx_page.php

```
<?php
    $select_type = $_GET['member_type'];
    $type = $_GET['sel_rad'];
?>
```

when i type in the textbox, it gives me an error as

`Notice: Undefined index: member_type in ajx_page.php on line 2`

That means `member_type` is not going in that page..

And when i comment all this code and put the below code in `ajx_page.php`

```
<?php
    echo "Name1\n";
    echo "Name2\n";
    echo "Name3\n"
?>
```

It displaying autocomplete feature list. but when i want to get the value of that object `member_type` it is saying an error..

**so how do i pass additional values using this autocomplete plugin**

I have added an Image to overwriting problem to @veeTrain

[image]

Comment: so how do i pass additional values using this autocomplete plugin

Comment: Do you want the member_type to send all its values or just the selected one?

Comment: You have noticed that the component has been deprecated and is not developed further (e.g. bugs won't get fixed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the autocomplete plugin is intended to handle this type of scenario or not.

However, if you want to manually pass these values into your php script, then it would be pretty simple (at least in this scenario where you are only trying to send two fields in).

```
var memberType = $("#member_type>option:selected").val();
var selRad = $("#resultant_text").val();
$("#resultant_text").autocomplete("ajx_page.php?member_type="+memberType+"&sel_rad="+selRad, {
//...
```

But this probably isn't  the answer answer you're looking for.

**Update**: I'm glad that syntax for sending the values is working for you.

It looks like you have overlapping ids being printed out -- is that what you mean by 'bold'? Apparently you aren't using the correct delimiter for creating a second auto-complete suggestion. I'm not sure what the autocomplete handler is wanting to delineate between items. Undefined is probably showing up because one of your items couldn't be found. You should use your browser's Developer Tools to debug what is getting sent.

Also, if you wanted the option's text rather than the `value` then you'll need to access the `.text()` rather than the `.val()` of the select drop down.

**Update**: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296842/jquery-autocomplete-with-php-source) might have something to say about what autocomplete is expecting.

Comment: it has accepted this syntax, but some autofields are overwriting.. and i have added an image of that.

Comment: @Rafee, it isn't clear to me what you're wanting now. Is it problematic that the text is overlapping within one line -- or that it says 'undefined'? You might be best served by asking a new question with what you're experiencing. I'll update my answer with a few thoughts.

Comment: Thanks man!, i got the solution, it was overlapping divs and i have rectified that problem. Thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 1):

I think to pass in additional parameter for bassistance's autocomplete, the only way is to modify the autocomplete.js file. I did something similar before, but the method is quite hardcoding. Posted below for your reference (it's around line 376):

```
$.ajax({
    // try to leverage ajaxQueue plugin to abort previous requests
    mode: "abort",
    // limit abortion to this input
    port: "autocomplete" + input.name,
    dataType: options.dataType,
    url: options.url,
    data: $.extend({
        member_type: ($("#member_type").length != 1)?$("#member_type").val():-1,
        q: lastWord(term),
        limit: options.max
    }, extraParams),
    success: function(data) {
        var parsed = options.parse && options.parse(data) || parse(data);
        cache.add(term, parsed);
        success(term, parsed);
    }
});
```

I only added one line to the original code, at line 10: `member_type: ...`.
Take note that I pass in "-1" if the object is not found on that page to prevent javascript error.
Hope it helps!